# How to display random product inside related product in woocommerce single product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using  Woodmart wordpress template.
By default related product show only category and tag.

I want category, then tag, then random product. And if some product have not present related product in same category or tag, it will showing random product on related product section

I found a code on this https://vincoding.com/randomize-woocommerce-related-products/ But I don't understand it will works or not.

The related product template are down blow. I am using grid template. Please help

```
    <?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$related_product_view = woodmart_get_opt( 'related_product_view' );

if ( $related_products ) : ?>

    <div class="related-products">
        
        <?php
        $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_related_products_heading', __( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ) );
        
        if ( $heading ) :
            ?>
        <h3 class="title slider-title"><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php 
        
            if ( $related_product_view == 'slider' ) {
                $slider_args = array(
                    'slides_per_view' => ( woodmart_get_opt( 'related_product_columns' ) ) ? woodmart_get_opt( 'related_product_columns' ) : apply_filters( 'woodmart_related_products_per_view', 4 ),
                    'img_size' => 'woocommerce_thumbnail',
                    'products_bordered_grid' => woodmart_get_opt( 'products_bordered_grid' ),
                    'custom_sizes' => apply_filters( 'woodmart_product_related_custom_sizes', false ),
                    'product_quantity' => woodmart_get_opt( 'product_quantity' )
                );
                
                woodmart_set_loop_prop( 'products_view', 'carousel' );

                echo woodmart_generate_posts_slider( $slider_args, false, $related_products );
            }elseif ( $related_product_view == 'grid' ) {
        
                woodmart_set_loop_prop( 'products_columns', woodmart_get_opt( 'related_product_columns' ) );
                woodmart_set_loop_prop( 'products_different_sizes', false );
                woodmart_set_loop_prop( 'products_masonry', false );
                woodmart_set_loop_prop( 'products_view', 'grid' );
                
                woocommerce_product_loop_start();

                foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) {
                    $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] = $post_object );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 
                }

                woocommerce_product_loop_end();
                
                woodmart_reset_loop();
                
                if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_reset_loop' ) ) woocommerce_reset_loop();
            }
            
        ?>
        
    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Did you try to print_r($related_products)? to check what is inside that variable.

Comment: **1)** 
The link you are referring to is 5 years old, so you can assume that more elegant solutions exist in the meantime. **2)** Your question requires custom code changes, 
as you can see in this RELATED answer: [Show cross-sells before same category on related products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62386535/11987538). So get started with that, and update your question with what you have achieved so far.

Comment: I just want to show random product not cross-sells product.