# Upsells by catergories and same brand

Tags: wordpress

I have a requirement to automatically populate upsells based on

- Products in same brand*
- products in same category
- Most expensive three results

**The client is using the product NAME as the brand*

The below returns no results, however, if you remove "Title" from the get_posts() query, it returns based soley on products of same category.

How can I get this to work with all of the 3 criteria above?

Thanks in advance

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_upsell_ids', 'custom_upsell_ids2', 20, 2 );
 function custom_upsell_ids2() {

 // Initialize
 global $product;
    $product_cats_ids = array();
    $product_cats_ids_unique = array();

        
        // Get product id
        $product->get_id();
        $name = $product->get_name();

        // Get current product categories id(s) & add to array
        $product_cats_ids = array_merge( $product_cats_ids, wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) );

    // Not empty
    if ( !empty( $product_cats_ids ) ) {
        // Removes duplicate values
        $product_cats_ids_unique = array_unique( $product_cats_ids, SORT_REGULAR );

        // Get product id(s) from a certain category, by category-id
      return get_posts( array(
            'title'           => $name,
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'numberposts' => 3,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'fields'      => 'ids',
            
            'tax_query'   => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => $product_cats_ids_unique,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )
            ),
        ) );
       
    }
     
}
```

My code is based on the following; I now need to extend it

[Show cross-sells before same category on related products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293670/show-cross-sells-before-same-category-on-related-products-in-woocommerce)